# Will there be a conflict when doing a merge after removing a particular branch folder?

Tags: git, gitlab, branch, git-merge

A project has two branches: master and dev.

Suppose a folder was removed from the dev branch, but not the master.

If a commit is sent to GitLab, will there be a conflict when merging?

Answer (score 2):

There might be *tree* conflicts if on the other branch one of those deleted files is modified, or renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Conflicts occur when there are different changes to the same lines of code in the same file on each branch. So the only way to be conflicts here is if some other work on `master` that modifies these files in some way, either by editing their contents or deleting or moving them.